# javascript array is coming as empty

Tags: javascript

I need to return whole object where linkable is true. I think I am doing it in a right way but array is coming as empty. this.releaseDescriptionDatesArray is empty even I am pushing the object.

```
for (const item of this.datesArray) {
          for (const attribute in item) {
            if (attribute === 'linkable' && item[attribute] === 'true') {
              this.releaseDescriptionDatesArray.push(item); // data is here 

              console.log(   this.releaseDescriptionDatesArray,  "datesArr");data is not coming here 
            }
          }
        }
    console.log(   this.releaseDescriptionDatesArray,  "datesArr"); data is not here 
      }
```

Sample data

```
       datesArray =  [ {
           "type": "disasterRecovery",
           "date": "2019-07-28",
           "releaseWindow":       {
              "start": null,
              "end": null
           },
           "description": "Disaster Recovery",
           "linkable": true
        },
           {
           "type": "nooutageRelease",
           "date": "2019-08-03",
           "releaseWindow":       {
              "start": "2019-08-04T00:00:00",
              "end": "2019-08-04T23:59:59"
           },
           "description": "Infrastructure Release (No Outage)",
           "linkable": true
        }]
```

Comment: `item[attribute] === true`.  Still you can skip the second for loop entirely and do `item.linkable === true`.

Comment: your code is a mini spaghetti dish. take the answer from **SuleymanSah**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know there is going to be an attribute `linkable` in every item, you don't need to parse every attribute of the items and check if one of them is `linkable` then check if it's true.

Also, since your are stritcly comparing your values (`===`), `'true' !== true`, that's probably why your array is empty. With that in mind, you could simply use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function on your array with a callback that check if  `linkable` is true. It will simplify a lot your code.

```js
let datesArray = [{
        "type": "disasterRecovery",
        "date": "2019-07-28",
        "releaseWindow": {
            "start": null,
            "end": null
        },
        "description": "Disaster Recovery",
        "linkable": true
    },
    // i've change the value of this item for testing purpose
    {
        "type": "nooutageRelease",
        "date": "2019-08-03",
        "releaseWindow": {
            "start": "2019-08-04T00:00:00",
            "end": "2019-08-04T23:59:59"
        },
        "description": "Infrastructure Release (No Outage)",
        "linkable": false
    }
];

// this callback will assert that date.linkable is not null,
// and that it's value is true.
// if the attribute was null ( or undefined ), it would be evaluated as "false-y" and therefore
// not be included in the final array.
// the last part also check that the value is an actual boolean ( see Lain's comment )
let output = datesArray.filter((date) => date.linkable && date.linkable === true);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Your explanation on `(date) => date.linkable` is inaccurate, since `linkable: 'no'` also would be valid. Still the only answer with some explanation of the actual issue.

Comment: @Lain you are right, let me edit that real quick. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

```
item[attribute] === true
```

You need to use boolean `true`, not string `'true'`

```
for (var item of datesArray) {
          for (var attribute in item) {
            if (attribute === 'linkable' && item[attribute] === true) {
              releaseDescriptionDatesArray.push(item); // data is here 
              console.log(attribute)
              console.log(this.releaseDescriptionDatesArray,  "datesArr");
            }
          }
}
```